# Scroll uitableview with slide uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've done a custom UITableViewCell` with a front view and a back view for doing something like mailbox.

I've added the `gestureRecognizer` to scroll the front view so

```
self.slideRecognizer = 
 [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slide:)];
[self.slideRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:self.slideRecognizer];
```

The problem is that I cant scroll the `UITableView` down unless I tap outside the `UITableViewCell` (for example on `UITableView` header) and go down.

There should be something to add or edit in my method

```
- (void)slide:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
```

It's true?

**THAT'S THE SOLUTION FOR ME** __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____

Based on Simon's link, I've added this code in my tableViewController and in my custom cell

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
           (UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

The problem was that assigning the custom pan `gestureRecognizer` I've invalidating the default one.

Comment: Try this link https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell. This is already implemented swiping cell ready to use.

Comment: If my answer solved your question please remember to mark it as top answer so that others will know that it solved the issue and I get the rep points. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at this question which seems quite similar. It sounds as though the gesture is only being captured by that cell and not passed through.

[Tell ScrollView to Scroll after other pan gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180613/tell-scrollview-to-scroll-after-other-pan-gesture)

I'm not sure if this is exactly the same issue as yours however. You should post more code.

On a side note, personally as a developer and a user I find scrolling elements inside scrolling elements to be every irritating to use. From a usability perspective I would consider a redesign. Thats only my opinion however.

Comment: I'm agree with you but I didn't choose myself the design. I read the link and changed the question consequently, thank you!